# Autologin with Inappbrowser on an external website?

Tags: javascript, cordova, autologin

I've built a native app with Phonegap Build. Is there a way to autologin in webview on an external website (embedded with inappbrowser).

The app starts and then the users will be redirecting to the website for login. But the users have to put in their username and password again and again. is there a possibility to autologin? Ive read about localstorage. Is that possible with the inappbrowser on a external website (there is no access to the phonegap plugins I know).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should be possible. You just need to connect proper handler to *loadstop* event and then use local storage to store the usernames and passwords once submit is hit and if already existing, auto-fill them.

```
function loadStopped() {
    // Here use JavaScript to manipulate the actual page on hand.
    // Can't really give better description about what to do, but something like this:
    var username = "";
    if (localStorage.getItem("username") !== null) {
        username = localStorage.getItem("username");
    }
    var password = "";
    if (localStorage.getItem("password") !== null) {
        password = localStorage.getItem("password");
    }
    document.getElementById("username_field").value = username;
    document.getElementById("password_field").value = password;
    // document.getElementById("the_form").submit();
    document.getElementById("the_form").addEventListener("submit", function() {
        localStorage.setItem("username", document.getElementById("username_field").value);
        localStorage.setItem("password", document.getElementById("password_field").value);
    });
}
ref = window.open('http://google.com', '_self', 'location=yes');
ref.addEventListener('loadstop', loadStopped);
```

Comment: Thank you. But I understand correctly? I need to enter the script to the index.html of Phonegap and then get redirected to the login page and will be logged in automatically?

Comment: Since you said you are using the InAppBrowser it means that you use _window.open_, right? The script should be used where ever you are opening the page in InAppBrowser.

Comment: I use 

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
function itsloaded() {
   document.addEventListener("deviceready", OnDeviceReady, false);
}
function OnDeviceReady() {
      navigator.splashscreen.hide();
   window.location = 'http://www.test.de/login';
}
</script>

in my index.html of phonegap. Sorry for my question: Where I have to input your script? At the index.html or the external page test.de/login ?

Comment: You probably should replace the `window.location` with it. You just need to change the _google.com_ to your address.

Comment: Sorry. My question was whether there is a possibility automatically log in the user if they have the data entered before.

Comment: Updated my answer to include also the localStorage.

Comment: you can also autosubmit with something like document.getElementById("the_form").submit();

Comment: @jcesarmobile: Which is exactly what is says on my answer already :)

Comment: This doesn't seem to be secure at all. Is there any other option to store it for example in KeyChain?