# How I can pass a value in localStorage to InAppBrowser using executescript event

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, local-storage, inappbrowser

I have a problem with the plugin InAppBrowser.

I would like to insert a value stored in localStorage from my ionic app in a form on my website (username and password). It works fine with a simple value like 'test', but when I want to insert a value like localStorage.getItem('onlineIdStore') nothing is happening. Do you have a solution?

I found a similar problem but the solution does not work for me: [Autologin with Inappbrowser on an external website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27766375/autologin-with-inappbrowser-on-an-external-website?answertab=active#tab-top)

Here is my code:

```
var ref = window.open('website', '_blank', 'location=no');
ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function(event) {
ref.executeScript({ code: "document.getElementById('doc_login_username').value = 'test' " }); 
   });
```

Comment: Are you running localStorage synchronously or asynchronous and is the value stored correctly in local storage can you view it in the developers console

Comment: Sorry I do not know what you mean by running synchronously I'm a beginner, but the variable and its value appear in the developers console, I think the problem is not with the localStorage but with the syntax in the executeScript. Thank you for your help

Comment: Async Meaning localStorage does not return the results of the query immediately you need a success handler.

Comment: Chances are you're running it sync which is good but have you checked that your browser is even compatible

Comment: Yes the browser is compatible, I have seen examples on the internet, some manage to collect website data in localStorage value, the opposite should be possible I think

Comment: Okay first remember that localStorage is stored similar to cookies they are attached to the domain they were created from. And then check and make sure your data is in your localStorage you should be able to view it from the resources tab in most developers consoles

Comment: The problem is that I use is the inappbrowser of cordova, which can only be opened on the phone once the app is built, I can't access the Developer tab on the phone. Actually what I want to do is to share localStorage value  between my application and the inappbrowser

Comment: Look up remote debugging that will be helpful to you both now and in the future. Aside from that put up the code that isn't working rather than the code that does that might help.

Comment: Ah okay thank you I will check that!

Comment: Here a clearer layout:
http://imgur.com/C5C8BQj

Comment: It's because of how you set up your string. It doesn't evaluate the variable you need to do something like "document.getElementById('doc_login_username').value='"+username+"';"

Comment: That way the variable is evaluated and added to the string

Comment: Yeah your solution works! Thank you!

Comment: Okay I'll oh it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem isn't localStorage it's your string your variables are in your current script so you need to evaluate the variables before its sent to the new window like this

```
var ref = window.open('website', '_blank', 'location=no');
ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function(event) {
ref.executeScript({ code: "document.getElementById('doc_login_username').value = '"+username+"'; " }); 
});
```