# Cordova inAppBrowser store and reuse credentials

Tags: javascript, cordova, local-storage, inappbrowser

**The case:**
I have a simple cordova app that opens the mobile version of a (Drupal 7) website using the inAppBrowser plugin. On the website, a user can log in to read more content. Also everyone that has the app installed, can get push notifications if accepted.

**The problem:** Users who have logged in are being logged out after a while. It happens on both iOS and Android.

Now I would like is that the app stores the filled in value of the username and password. So when the user is being logged out it has it's credentials filled in. Is anyone able to help?

I have found a few similar question on the web, but I can't seem to get it to work using localStorage.

This is a snippet I found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27766375/autologin-with-inappbrowser-on-an-external-website) question. But I can't get it to work. the `edit-name` and `edit-pass` are the id's of the input fields on the website.

```
function loadStopped() {
           var username = "";
           if (localStorage.getItem("username") !== null) {
               username = localStorage.getItem("username");
           }
           var password = "";
           if (localStorage.getItem("password") !== null) {
               password = localStorage.getItem("password");
           }
           document.getElementById("edit-name").value = username;
           document.getElementById("edit-pass").value = password;

           document.getElementById("the_form").addEventListener("submit", function() {
               localStorage.setItem("username", document.getElementById("edit-name").value);
               localStorage.setItem("password", document.getElementById("edit-pass").value);
           });
       }
```

My full code:

```js
var app = {

        // Application Constructor
        browser: null,
        host: 'http://www.somewebsite.com/',

        initialize: function () {
            this.bindEvents();
        },

        // Bind Event Listeners
        bindEvents: function () {
            document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);

        },

        // deviceready Event Handler

        onDeviceReady: function () {
            app.checkConnection();
            app.initPushwoosh();
        },

        checkConnection: function () {
            var networkState = navigator.connection.type;

            var states = {};
            states[Connection.NONE] = 'no connection';

            //if no connection show popup
            if (networkState === Connection.NONE) {
                navigator.notification.alert(
                    'Please enable your internet connection\nand restart the app',  // message
                    function () {
                    },         // callback
                    'Oops no internet',            // title
                    'Ok'                  // buttonName
                );
                //if network is found, launch inappbrowser
            } else {
                app.openBrowser('/');

            }
        },

        openBrowser: function (url) {
            
           function loadStopped() {
               var username = "";
               if (localStorage.getItem("username") !== null) {
                   username = localStorage.getItem("username");
               }
               var password = "";
               if (localStorage.getItem("password") !== null) {
                   password = localStorage.getItem("password");
               }
               document.getElementById("edit-name").value = username;
               document.getElementById("edit-pass").value = password;
               
               document.getElementById("the_form").addEventListener("submit", function() {
                   localStorage.setItem("username", document.getElementById("edit-name").value);
                   localStorage.setItem("password", document.getElementById("edit-pass").value);
               });
           }

            if (url.indexOf('/') !== 0) {
                url = '/' + url;
            }
            url = this.updateQueryStringParameter(url, 'app_os', 'mobile');

            window.open = cordova.InAppBrowser.open;
            this.browser = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(this.host + url, '_blank', 'location=no,hidden=no');
            
           this.browser.addEventListener('loadstop', loadstopped);
            
            this.browser.addEventListener('loadstop', function(e)){
                var username="";
                if (localStorage.getItem("username") !== null){
                    username = localStorage.getItem("username");
                }
                
                this.browser.executeScript({
                                           code:"document.getElementById('edit-name').value;"
                                           });
            });


             this.browser.addEventListener('exit', function (e) {
                 if (navigator.app) {
                     navigator.app.exitApp();
                 } else if (navigator.device) {
                     navigator.device.exitApp();
                 } else {
                     window.close();
                 }
             });
            
            

        },


        // Update DOM on a Received Event
        receivedEvent: function (id) {
            var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
            var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
            var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

            listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
            receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

            console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
        },

        updateQueryStringParameter: function(uri, key, value) {
            // remove the hash part before operating on the uri
            var i = uri.indexOf('#');
            var hash = i === -1 ? ''  : uri.substr(i);
            uri = i === -1 ? uri : uri.substr(0, i);

            var re = new RegExp("([?&])" + key + "=.*?(&|$)", "i");
            var separator = uri.indexOf('?') !== -1 ? "&" : "?";

            if (!value) {
                // remove key-value pair if value is empty
                uri = uri.replace(new RegExp("([&]?)" + key + "=.*?(&|$)", "i"), '');
                if (uri.slice(-1) === '?') {
                    uri = uri.slice(0, -1);
                }
            } else if (uri.match(re)) {
                uri = uri.replace(re, '$1' + key + "=" + value + '$2');
            } else {
                uri = uri + separator + key + "=" + value;
            }
            return uri + hash;
        }

};

app.initialize();
```

Anyone who could tell me what I'm doing wrong or can give me a detailed 'guide' of how I can get it to work?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: may be the session ended because of the server side?

Comment: i made the same way for login checking for cordova just like yours.. and have no problem at all..but i did not accessing the page itself directly so i make another page using F7 UI framework then access everything on pagesite data using ajax request..

Comment: @aswzenThank you for your comment but unfortunately that isn't much of help to me.